# How to add the startup view without the Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar controller in my app.

It opens "Quotes of the day" view everytime the user starts the app.

This view is placed in the first tab. It goes away only if user presses a button on the Quotes page.

I want to remove Quotes from tab bar controller. Tab bar should be displayed only when Quotes view is unloaded.

How can I do this?

Are there any shorter and better way to do this?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

1. Remove the Quotes view from your tab
   bar controller.
2. Set the default view of the tab bar
   controller to whatever view you
   want.
3. Make the Quotes view a subview of
   that view, that pops to top on start
   of your app.
4. On the dismiss function of your
   Quotes view, call
   removeFromSuperview on your Quotes
   view.

Just add hide/show functionality to the tab bar controller where you need to.